# Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling RetryPolicy and Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll

Tags: azure, cloud, servicebus

Hopefully this is a simple one and I'm doing something stupid.  I have a web app on .Net 4.5 in VS 2012 which at some point invokes a method which in turn sends a message to a Service Bus in Azure.  A service running locally then retrieves this message and processes it.  Great.

However, I consistently get exceptions (VS set to break on unhandled) which give the familiar file load exception on Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll version 1.6.0.0, the versions on the machine are 1.7.x.x or 1.8.x.x.  I can successfully send and receive messages so I'm not sure what impact this is having! but it only occurs when invoking service bus calls through the very useful RetryPolicy class via the ExecuteAction method in the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling namespace.  I can only assume that this component is built against 1.6.0.0 but I appear to have the latest version.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and how best to work around it?  Is it wise to run two versions of Microsoft.ServiceBus? ie. 1.6.0.0 for the cloud service and 1.7/1.8.x.x for the web application?  Where can I get 1.6.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Azure SDK 1.6 contains Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll 1.6 (that's the November 2011 release). You can [get it from here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/14/windows-azure-sdk-1-6-build-1-6-41103-1601-installation-walkthrough.aspx)

Now, are you certain that the EnterpriseLibrary is looking for that specific version? In the past (I don't recall exactly when), the SB assembly was added to the GAC when installing the SDK, so perhaps the library is expecting the SB assembly to be GACced. You might want to use fusion logs to validate this before using a year+ old version of the Service Bus dll.